# Grunt JS copy to network location

Tags: copy, gruntjs

I want to use grunt-contrib-copy (or any other grunt copying plugin) to copy files to network location.

Trying below:

```
    copy: {
        test: {
            files: [
                { src: ['Scripts/*'], dest: ['\\\\location\\site\\Scripts\'] }
            ]
        }
    }
```

but getting:

**Warning: Unable to write "\\location\site\Scripts\" file (Err
or code: undefined). Use --force to continue.**

Is it possible / How to copy to network location?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's quite simple to do, just define your path with forward slashes:

```
copy: {
     test: {
         files: [
             { src: ['Scripts/*'], dest: ['//location/site/Scripts/'] }
         ]
     }
}
```

This will work on windows as-well, grunt will take care of that. Try it out.

Comment: dest isn't allowed to be an array (so no square brackets around the location).
Otherwise you get this error:
Warning: Arguments to path.join must be strings.

Once I removed the square brackets it worked for me :)

Comment: This fails on some macs with this error:
`Running "copy" (copy) task
Warning: Unable to create directory "/location" (Error code: EACCES). Use --force to continue.`

Comment: It looks that for windows the UNC path works very well. I have done some configuration using both source and dest with UNC path.

Comment: If you are mapping from Mac to a Windows (parallels drive). You may need to put //Volumes/ at the start of your destination path.

Answer (score -1):

to copy files from mac to windows shared directory prepend the destination with smb:

```
copy: {
  test: {
    files: [
      { src: ['Scripts/*'], dest: ['smb://location/site/Scripts/'] }
    ]
  }
}
```

kr,
Joachim

Comment: This does not work (see also https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/208)