# Grunt Copy from Windows C Drive to Mapped Network Drive

Tags: windows, gruntjs, network-drive, grunt-contrib-copy

### Background

I have a local set of files on my computer, under `C:/websites/PROJECT`. I would like to use Grunt to copy these files to a live server when I'm ready to push changes. I have access to the live server, which is self hosted. I can access it several ways. *(Names and IP addresses changed for privacy concerns)*

First off, it's a Mapped Network Drive, so accessible under:

```
K:\
```

Second, I can access it under the Network portion of Windows Explorer, through it's computer name.

```
\\SERVER1-NAME\PROJECT
```

Third, I know the internal IP of the computer:

```
\\192.168.1.1\PROJECT
```

### Grunt Code:

```
copy: {
    options: {
        force: true
    },
    files: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'C:/websites/PROJECT/src',  // set working folder / root to copy
        src: [
            '**/*'
        ],
        dest: '//192.168.1.1/PROJECT' // destination folder
    }
},
```

I have tried all of these for `dest`:

```
'//K:/PROJECT'
'//SERVER1/PROJECT'
'//192.168.1.1/PROJECT'

'\\\\K:\\PROJECT'
'\\\\SERVER1\\PROJECT'
'\\\\192.168.1.1\\PROJECT'
```

All of them give me errors. Most of the time, they also end up creating an empty folder on the `C` drive as well. Example: `C:/192.168.1.1`.

I found this: [Grunt JS copy to network location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541233/grunt-js-copy-to-network-location)

But when I tried it, it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

It appears that this just doesn't work.

#### Followup

As an alternative, I just set up SFTP access, and used [grunt-sftp-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sftp-deploy)